# preg_match_all with surrounding data

Tags: php, regex

I have a large amount of log data that I need to get some relevant information out of.
The syntax is:

```
WORD1 some text KEYWORD some text WORD2 WORD1 some text KEYWORD some text WORD2 WORD1 some text KEYWORD some text WORD2 WORD1 some text KEYWORD some text WORD2
```

Would it be possible to use regex to get a certain block out of it - so that when I queried some keyword it would return `WORD1 some text THIS_KEYWORD some text WORD2`

PS: There could be multiple instances of one keyword, it should return all of the blocks (preg_match_all, PREG_SET_ORDER?).

Comment: will there always be `WORD1` and `WORD2` as shown ?

Comment: yes, it's basically a system log file that has certain words starting and finishing each block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you comment there will always be starting and finishing word for each block.

You can do the following:

- Split the input string into blocks
  (array). An end of the block is
  identified by the whitespace which is
  followed by `WORD2` and preceded by
  `WORD1`.
- Search the array we got above for the
  keyword.

.

```
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=WORD2)\s+(?=WORD1)/',$log);
$keyword = 'KEYWORD1';
$result = preg_grep("/\b$keyword\b/",$arr);
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/sncHM)

Answer (score 0):

use UNGREEDY modifier

```
$found = preg_match_all("/WORD1.*KEYWORD.*WORD2/U",$x,$match);
if($found) print_r($match[0]);
```

Comment: Will not work. Consider `$x = WORD1 foo KEYWORDx bar WORD2 WORD1 foo KEYWORD bar WORD2`

Comment: Misunderstood. I considered KEYWORD as any part of substring. In your point, the regexp should of course be "/WORD1.*\bKEYWORD\b.*WORD2/U"